# How do I handle streaming data in tornado asynchronously, while handling the response code synchronously?

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, tornado

My tornado API call will be calling another URL, then streaming the result back to the client. However, if the internal URL returns an error code, I want to handle my own error separately, and stream the error content to the client. What I currently have is this:

```
@web.asynchronous
@gen.coroutine
def get(self, job_id):
    url = ...
    client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    # handle_chunk will forward received bytes to the client, allowing
    # other HTTP requests to be handled concurrently
    response = yield client.fetch(httpclient.HTTPRequest(
        url=url,
        streaming_callback=self._handle_chunk))
    self.finish()

def _handle_chunk(self, chunk):
    self.write(chunk)
    self.flush()
```

I need to modify this to only start forwarding chunks if the response code is in the 200 family, but the response isn't yielded by `client.fetch` until the whole request is complete. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use both `streaming_callback` and `header_callback`. The header callback will be run before the first call to `streaming_callback`, with the headers as a list of strings. The headers start with the status line which you'll have to parse yourself:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self, job_id):
    url = ...
    client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    response = yield client.fetch(httpclient.HTTPRequest(
        url=url,
        header_callback=self._handle_headers,
        streaming_callback=self._handle_chunk))
    if response.code != 200:
        # handle error
    self.finish()

def _handle_headers(self, headers):
    self._start_line = tornado.httputil.parse_response_start_line(headers[0])

def _handle_chunk(self, chunk):
    if self._start_line.code == 200:
        self.write(chunk)
        self.flush()
```

It's not currently possible to cleanly cancel a request; if the status code is not 200, your callback will have to accept the streaming chunks and ignore them (and then you return an error elsewhere).

Comment: Is the `header_callback` guaranteed to be called before and of the `streaming_callback` calls?

Comment: Yes, header_callback is always called before the first streaming_callback. (if the connection succeeds. If there is a failure before the connection is made, `yield client.fetch()` will raise an error without calling either callback)

Comment: Please don't post comments on old answers with entirely new questions to discuss. Post a new question.